# Angular and spring server caching .js and .html files

Tags: angularjs, spring, google-chrome, ubuntu, caching

I'm using angular with spring server and every time I'm changing .js or .html files, I have to restart the server to see changes in browser. How can I avoid that?

I'm using chrome and firefox on ubuntu and nothing works (I've tried to stop caching in firebugs and many other solutions).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling cache on Google Chrome.

From View menu -> Developer -> Javascript console -> Network tab, check "Disable cache".

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was running server from STS (Spring Tool Suite). When I'm running server typing mvn spring-boot:run in console, everything is all right.